# How to display on UI the CLI output on the remote server

Tags: services

My custom Drupal module connects to remote server through SSH and executes several commands there. I don't want to keep Drupal user left completely blank during the process.

As the last resort, I will have to use some kind of pseudo-progress bar, however ideally I'd prefer to show the progress that is going on the remote server's CLI.

I wonder is there any way Drupal could display output of the things that are taking place in (local or remote doesn't matter in fact) server's CLI?

Comment: If your remote server provides progress reports then yes, you can use PECL uploadprogress or equivalent to achieve that. There's very little Drupal-related about it though

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that this is more general type question, but since I'd like to implement it on Drupal I hoped there are some modules related to JSON or something like that would allow tracking progress on CLI.

Comment: Have you considered using Drupals batch api? This would give you a progress bar and you have the opportunity to display a message under the progress bar as each step is completed.